# Equivalent definition of Kan fibration

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $\Lambda^n_k$ be the $k$-th [horn](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/horn) of the standard $n$-simplex $\Delta^n$, and let $Y$ be a simplicial set.

In *Simplicial Homotopy Theory*, pg. 10, we find that the coequalizer description of the horn implies a correspondence between

- morphisms of simplicial sets $\Lambda^n_k\to Y$.
- tuples $(y_0,\dots,\hat y_k,\dots,y_n)$ of $n-1$-simplices, such that $d_i(y_j) = d_{j-1}(y_i)$ if $i<j$, $j\neq k$.

In the next page, Kan fibrations are defined in the standard way, as morphisms $p:X\to Y$ with the RLP against horn inclusions $\Lambda^n_k\hookrightarrow \Delta^n$:

What I don't get is the following quote from the book:

> The condition (defining Kan fibrations) amount to saying that if $(x_0,\dots,\hat x_k,\dots,x_n)$ is an $n$-tuple of $n-1$-simplices of $X$ such that $d_ix_j = d_{j-1}x_i$ if $i<j$, $j\neq k$, and there is an $n$-simplex $y$ of $Y$ such that $d_iy = p(x_i)$, then there is an $n$-simplex $x$ of $X$ such that $d_ix = x_i$, $i\neq k$, and such that $p(x) = y$.

It seems that this phrase is implicitly implying that

> Precomposition of $\Lambda^n_k\to \Delta^n$ with an $n$-simplex $y:\Delta^n\to Y$ defines a horn $(y_0,\dots,\hat y_k,\dots,y_n)$ such that $d_iy = y_i$.

I can't see why this is true.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can see, if you write out carefully the correspondence between the two bullet items at the beginning of the question, and also write out carefully the definition of the inclusions $\Lambda^n_k\to\Delta^n$, then you'll automatically get the equations $d_iy=y_i$ that you need.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly you're asking about. It seems like you're asking about the sentence you've written in your last blockquote, but I don't understand what you're finding confusing about that sentence. Can you be more explicit about what your question is?

Comment: I couldn't deduce the last blockquote from the previous results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via the correspondence mentioned in the answer, the inclusion $\Lambda^n_k\hookrightarrow\Delta^n$ is the $n$-tuple of $n-1$-simplices
$$
(d_1(\iota),\dots,\hat d_k(\iota),\dots,d_n(\iota)),
$$
where $\iota:\Delta^n_{n-1}\to\Delta^n_{n-1}$ is the identity.

The composite $\Lambda^n_k\hookrightarrow \Delta^n\xrightarrow{y} Y$ iteslf is an $n$-tuple of $n-1$-simplices in $Y$:
$$
(y_1,\dots,\hat y_k,\dots,y_n),
$$
From the discussion above this tuple is explicitly given by
$$
(d_1(y),\dots,\hat d_k(y),\dots,d_n(y)),
$$

The result $d_i y = y_i$ follows.
Please correct me for any errors or imprecisions.

Comment: I'm still a little skeptical of the first claim, but I bet it should follows quickly from the coequalizer description.